# jQuery: selected dropdown option returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a functionality where in a table, I can click an add button and a new tr gets prepended to the table. However, I want field AddOn to get disabled if a certain food category is selected. It is easy to tackle it on change but how to do it when I click on add and depending on the value originally selected in dropdown?

```
var index = 0;
var FoodCategory = "FoodCategory" + index;
var tr = '<tr class="row">' + 
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td><select id="' +      FoodCategory + '" type="text" class="form-control"  /><span id="FoodCat""></select></span></td>' +
            '<td><span><select id="' + AddOns + '" class="form-control"></select></span><span id="AddOns"></span></td>' +
            '</tr>';
("#tblFood").prepend(tr);
```

I'm trying to access the value of FoodCategory to disable the select of AddOns by

`$('#'+FoodCategory).val()` but it is not working.

Comment: On load, the row is not yet appended. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Both `select` that are appended are empty. Edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), focussing on 'complete'.